# Cannot find the auxiliary latex files in the directory

Tags: errors, miktex, compiling, directory

I am using Texmaker 5.1.3 (compiled with Qt 5.15.2).

I started writing a latex file and saved it in the usual directory. Now, I can't find any of the TeX auxiliary files when I go to this directory on my computer. It is strange because whenever I click on file>>open recent sessions: the file appears to be in the directory. The issue happens for all the other TeX files I started lately. Any ideas?

I am not fluent in LaTeX at all. I am attaching screenshots:

[image]

Comment: probably unrelated but you shouldn't store your files in local/temp. That is a folder for temporary files.